# Como gerar um setup no visual studio 2012?

Tags: c#

Estou com dificuldade em gerar uma *setup* no Visual Studio 2012.

Não vejo a opção de gerar *setup*, tentei criar uma *setup* com o Inno Setup, criou normalmente mas ao instalar na máquina esta dar erro de conexão com a base de dado.

Comment: Não estou muito familiarizado com o Visual Studio, mas acredito que mesmo criando um setup através do Visual Studio o seu erro de ligação à base de dados irá se manter.  A base de dados é local ou remota?

Comment: O que sugeris então?

Comment: Eu tentaria perceber o porquê no erro da ligação à base de dados.

Comment: Já fiz uma análise e até onde eu pode perceber é que estou a cometer algum erro ao gerar o setup com o inno setup, mas não sei qual, por isso que estou a pedir ideias diferente de como gerar um setup quer seja com visual studio 2012 ou mesmo com o ino setup.

Comment: Se quiser continuar usando o VS talvez isso te ajude: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybshs20f(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: A base de dados é local ou remota?